# Search and then modify the result input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Goal**: Search must work correctly and then be able to modify the found input. I'm trying to figure out why I can't do both.

**Observation**: the crazy thing I found is it works if I change the key from `key={index}` to `key={variable.value}` which doesn't make any sense.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if there's any way to do this better?

You'll understand better if you look at the [**codesandbox DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/6x7x1jzkln)

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Input from './Input'

const dummyVariablies = [
  {
    name: 'barrack',
    value: 11
  },
  {
    name: 'putin',
    value: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'trump',
    value: 33
  }
]

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: ''
  }

  handleSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value
    })
  }

  getFilteredVariables = (variables) => {
    const { search } = this.state;
    return variables.filter(
      variable => variable.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toString().toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  render() {
    const variables = this.getFilteredVariables(dummyVariablies || [])
    return (
      <div>
        Goal: Search must work correctly and then be able to modify the found input
        <br /> <br /> <br />
        Search: <input onChange={this.handleSearch} />
        <br /> <br /> <br />
        {variables.map((variable, index) => {
          return <Input variable={variable} key={index}  />
        })
        }               
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Input.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Input extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    value: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        value: this.props.variable.value,
        name: this.props.variable.name
      }
    )
  }

  // static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
  //   return {
  //     value: nextProps.variable.value,
  //     name: nextProps.variable.name
  //   }
  // }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { value, name } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {name}
        <input type="text"
          value={value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `index` as `key` if the array will be manipulated in any way except just adding new ones at the end. You could add a placeholder `id` for each object in the array, so that React knows which component belongs to what element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6vk3ym4q3z)

As you can see I changed the input:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Input extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.variable.value
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.variable.name}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem with your code is that you're sending props to your `Input` but you're not handling the updates correctly. You're only doing it once, because `componentDidMount` runs only once when the component is loaded. I simplified it and I'm just passing the props down. This way the filtration works fine.

Keep in mind that if you want to save the values correctly after you edit the inputs you'll have to insert `dummyVariablies` inside the state of `App` and then use `lifting state up` from your Input component. Good example can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).